# navigator.getusermedia

Tags: html

I was playing around with the html5 new specifications, precisely the webcam functionalities.

By [following this tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/playing-with-html5-video-and-getusermedia-support/). I was getting the following error:

```
Native web camera streaming (getUserMedia) is not supported in this browser.
```

which was taken by this if statement:

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia)
```

now, I am sure that navigator.getUserMedia is enabled in my browser, as these examples [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) work perfectly

so, I modified the code in the if, with the following:

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)
```

but now, I am getting a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Navigator> has no method 'getUserMedia'
```

at this line here:

```
navigator.getUserMedia('video', successCallback, errorCallback);
```

which doesn't really make sense! it IS working on the last link i posted!

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you also modify the calls to `getUserMedia()` to fall back to browser specific versions?  You'll get more help if you paste the exact code you are trying into your question.

Comment: have a look a the edit, that's the line that is giving me the error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're testing for `navigator.getUserMedia`, `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`, `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` and `navigator.msGetUserMedia` then you have no guarantee that `navigator.getUserMedia()` is available.  It could be that or any one of the other three.  You could try something like this (from [getUserMedia.js](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js)):

```
navigator.getUserMedia_ = (   navigator.getUserMedia
                           || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
                           || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
                           || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

if ( !! navigator.getUserMedia_) {
    navigator.getUserMedia_('video', successCallback, errorCallback);
    //The rest of your code
```

Comment: wow! that's pretty impressive! although the code is not working, I guess I can use that library and have a flash fallback, too. thank you!

Comment: `navigator.msGetUserMedia` has never existed on any browser ever! Shout out to [this newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56939752/918910) instead.

Comment: Also note that the getUSerMEdia works on https only

Answer (score 7):

`navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated. See MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Answer (score 3):

This is a new technology. Yoy must have a Firefox/Chrome/Opera browser and it has to be updated. Then, try this:

```
function showCamera()  {   var streaming = false,
      video        = window.content.document.createElement("video"),
      cover        = window.content.document.createElement("div"),
      canvas       = window.content.document.createElement("canvas"),
      photo        = window.content.document.createElement("img"),
      startbutton  = window.content.document.createElement("button"),
      width = 320,
      height = 0;

  photo.src = "http://placekitten.com/g/320/261";   window.content.document.body.insertBefore(video, window.content.document.body.firstChild);

  var navigator = window.navigator;
    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    navigator.getMedia(
    {
      video: true,
      audio: false
    },
    function(stream) {
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
      } else {
        var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
      }
      video.play();
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    }   );
    video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
    }   }, false);
    function takepicture() {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);   }
    startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();   }, false);   }


showCamera();
```

If your browser is Firefox and still not working, go to about:config and set/add a boolean variable with a true value called media.navigator.enabled

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/Taking_webcam_photos

P/d: I used this code in a Greasemonkey script and it worked. I did some few changes on firsts lines of the original code.