# javascript record screen error on mobile device

Tags: javascript, ios, cross-browser, recording, screen-recording

**Summary of problem:
A Javascript solution to record screen works on desktop versions of browsers (chrome, edge, firefox), but not on mobile browsers (chrome, safari).**

Following [this great example](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/vanilla-javascript-based-screen-recorder-29fff1cc7b00) I was able to build a prototype that works just fine on desktop browsers (tested on Chrome, Edge, Firefox).

However when testing on mobile browser (chrome/safari on ios), there is an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near
> '...navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia...')

Below is the HTML code for on-screen buttons:

```
        <input id="btnStartRecording" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-4" onclick="startRecord()" value="Start Recording" type="button">
        <input id="btnStopRecording" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-4 invisible" onclick="stopScreen()" value="Stop Recording" type="button">
        <a id="btnDownloadRecording" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-4 text-white invisible">Download Video</a>
```

Below is a hidden video element to hold the recording, and script to record:

```
    <div>
        <video controls="true" style="display: none" id="videoResult" src=""></video>
    </div>
    <script> // client side recording script https://javascript.plainenglish.io/vanilla-javascript-based-screen-recorder-29fff1cc7b00
        let completeBlob = null
        let recorder = null
        let chunks = [];
        let stream = null
        async function startRecord() {
            chunks = []; // need to reset chucks each time recording is started

            try {

                stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                    video: {
                        mediaSource: 'screen'
                    },
                })

                recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => chunks.push(e.data);
                recorder.start();
                recorder.onstop = onstop

                $("#btnStartRecording").addClass("invisible");
                $("#btnStopRecording").removeClass("invisible");
                $("#btnDownloadRecording").addClass("invisible");

            } catch (error) {

                navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia; 

                if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
                        function (streamobj) {

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder(streamobj);
                            recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => chunks.push(e.data);
                            recorder.start();
                            recorder.onstop = onstop

                            $("#btnStartRecording").addClass("invisible");
                            $("#btnStopRecording").removeClass("invisible");
                            $("#btnDownloadRecording").addClass("invisible");

                            //var video = document.querySelector('video');
                            //video.srcObject = stream;
                            //video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                            //    video.play();
                            //};
                        },
                        function (err) {
                            window.alert("#1 " + err)
                        }
                    );
                }
                else {
                    window.alert("#2 " + error)
                }
            }
        }


        async function stopScreen() {
            recorder.stop();
            //document.getElementById("stopBtn").style.display = "none";
            $("#btnStartRecording").removeClass("invisible");
            $("#btnStopRecording").addClass("invisible");
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                track.stop();
            });
        }

        function onstop() {
            console.log("onstop");
            completeBlob = new Blob(chunks, {
                type: chunks[0].type
            });
            $("#btnDownloadRecording").removeClass("invisible");
            let downloadButton = document.getElementById('btnDownloadRecording');
            let video = document.getElementById('videoResult');
            //video.style.display = 'block'
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(completeBlob);
            //downloadButton.style.display = 'unset'
            downloadButton.href = URL.createObjectURL(completeBlob);
            downloadButton.download = Date.now() + '.mp4';
        }
    </script>
```

Being not familiar with the APIs I used some SO threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407321/navigator-getusermedia) as reference to handle when "navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia" failed, which is the code in the "catch" part. But obviously it still does not work on mobile. Once accessed, the `window.alert("#2 " + error)` line was executed, which implies `if (navigator.getUserMedia)` evaluates to false.

Further digging found [`this SO discussion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084076/ios13-getusermedia-not-working-on-chrome-and-edge) which says only Safari works but I tested it on Safari and it failed with the same error message.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: getDisplayMedia() is not supported on mobile browsers as shown [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=getdisplaymedia)